# How to move my div element up with hover effect

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, hover

So I have some code, I think it's 80% true but I don't know why my div is cutting my image by hover. My padding p-1 is removed from top when the hover is active. How I can move my div up by hover without cutting image from top?

```css
.move {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}

.hover:hover .move {
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.hover:hover {
  background: black;
}

.readmore {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.hover:hover .readmore {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5 pt-5 ">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center text-center  ">
    <div class="col-md-3  hover p-0">
      <div class="position-relative  move  d-flex  align-items-end p-1 ">
        <div class="position-absolute pb-3">
          <h1 class="headersize">asd</h1>
          <p class="small-text">
            Small text
          </p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images? 
      q=tbn:ANd9GcQzp0rXN9BsNzMPYmzdT6xWc931So2I5sA4YiBX4Nm0rT6MiPBS" class=" 
      mb-4" />
      </div>
      <div class=" mb-3">
        <button type="button" class="readmore p-2 m-2    ">
                    Read More
                  </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, using negative margins inside `display: flex` container doesn't affect the margin of the container element, meaning its background color won't be affected if the child element `.move` is given a negative margin value.

You could try changing the code to not use flexbox.

OR, you could try applying negative `margin-top` to the **same** element as the one that gets `background-color` applied on hover:

```
/* .hover instead of .move */
.hover {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}

.hover:hover {
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.hover:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

Now you're coloring and moving the *same* element, which gives the illusion that it's a coherent move animation. However, once you give `.container` or `.row` a background color, you'll get the same "error".

Answer (score 0):

I did some fixes here. Hope it will help

```css
.move, .mb-3, .hover {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in; 
  }

.hover {
  position: relative;
  /* height: 80px; */
}
 .hover:hover .move {
  margin-top:-50px;
  background: black;

}

.hover:hover .mb-3 {
  background : black;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  
}



 .hover:hover {
 background: black;
 }

.readmore {
 opacity: 0;
 /* visibility: hidden; */
 transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
 }

.hover:hover .readmore {
 opacity: 1;
 /* visibility: visible; */
 transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-5 pt-5 ">
 <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center text-center  ">
 <div class="col-md-3  hover p-0">
 <div class="position-relative  move  d-flex  align-items-end p-1 ">
              <div class="position-absolute pb-3">
                <h1 class="headersize">asd</h1>
                <p class="small-text">
                 Small text
                </p>
              </div>
 <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images? 
  q=tbn:ANd9GcQzp0rXN9BsNzMPYmzdT6xWc931So2I5sA4YiBX4Nm0rT6MiPBS" class=" 
  mb-4" />
            </div>
            <div class=" mb-3">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="readmore p-2 m-2    "
              >
                Read More
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```